# help with laurent series

Tags: laurent-series

The book says:

The Laurent series converges and represents $F(z)$ in the open annulus obtained by continuously increasing the radius of $C_2$ and decreasing the radius of $C_1$ until each of $C_1$ and $C_2$ reaches a point where $F(z)$ is singular.

How can I find the region of convergence when the function is:

$$X(z) = \frac{1}{1-z^2}$$

edit: there are 2 regions: $|z| < 1$ and $|z| > 1$ ?

Thanks

Comment: At which points is $X$ singular?

Comment: z = 1 and z = -1

Comment: What is your Laurent series?

Comment: The region of convergence depends on the point of expansion. Is it in powers of $(z-2)$ or in powers of $z$ -- the answers are different.

Comment: Yes what @Thursday said is right. It depends upon the center of your annulus.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put that on the question. I have to find all laurent series for this function with center in z=0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac1{1-z^2}$ centered at $z=0$. There is the normal Taylor series:
$$
\frac1{1-z^2}=1+z^2+z^4+z^6+\dots
$$
which converges for $|z|\lt1$. Then there is the series
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{1-z^2}
&=\frac1{z^2}\frac1{\frac1{z^2}-1}\\
&=-\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{z^4}-\frac1{z^6}-\frac1{z^8}-\dots
\end{align}
$$
which converges for $|z|\gt1$. The second series can be simply derived from the first.

Comment: I'm working on a great solution of it.